# Android ListView custom row layout

Tags: java, android, listview, mobile

I need to set a background color and icon image for each item/row in the list view. ArrayAdapter set a single layout to all the items to be added to the list and I tried to catch every item getChildAt() but it fails !!

simply, I need to build a listview like that :

[image: Example]

BTW, It will be used inside the navigation drawer, as shown :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "BaseAdapter" for this task, check the link blow, and customize the example according to your need.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

you can also check this

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to define your own custom adapter (look [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown) for info on that) and then you'll be able to do custom layouts for individual list view items