# How can I add text multiple text views to the list view items in android?

Tags: android

How can I add text multiple text views to the list view items in android?Please add the code

Comment: Can't understand your question. need some more detail

Comment: "Please add the code" - please add yours.

Comment: @MathaN .........I am having a list view and and having an list view item called Quantity.I need to show text views based on the quantity value.If quantity=2 then need to show 2 text views

Comment: See the answer it may be fit for your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ListView custom row layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741361/android-listview-custom-row-layout)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any research effort

Answer (score 2):

You have to override your default listview items by your custom layout.
in `onCreate()` use:

```
    yourList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourList);
arrayAdapter = new MyClassAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
    yourList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

in `public class MyClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Long> {`

override this:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup list) {
View element;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    element = View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.yourlayout, null);
                } else {
                    element = convertView;
                }
///setup your listview element
return element;
    }
```

in `res/layout/yourlayout.xml` file create content like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**updated**
in `res/layout/yourlayout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

     </LinearLayout>
```

in `onCreate()`:  `arrayAdapter.setQ(2);`

in `public class MyClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Long> {`

```
public class MyClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Long> {
private int q = 2;
public void setQ(int num){
this.q = num;
}

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup list) {
    ViewGroup element;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                        element = (ViewGroup) View.inflate(ctx, R.layout.yourlayout, null);
                    } else {
                        element = (ViewGroup) convertView;
                    }
element.removeAllViews();
for (int i = 0; i < q; i++){
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("blablabla");
element.addChild(tv);
}
    ///setup your listview element
    return element;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Inflate yor ListView and in your ListItem view add as many TextViews you want.

Here see the example for [reference & sample](http://publicstaticdroidmain.com/2011/12/building-a-custom-multi-line-listview-in-android/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a adapter layout like below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/headerlayoutid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="Vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

In your adapter page use this below code to create dynamic textviews.

```
 final TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setText("String value");
    t.setTextSize(14);
//You can set gravity for the textview
    t.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.headerlayoutid);
   ll.addView(t);
```

If you need many textview then use the code in for loop. That's enough